# What package could I download to import tensorflow_decision_forests in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, random-forest

I am trying to install tensorflow_decision_forests from the command prompt but I get the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow_decision_forests
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow_decision_forests
I am searching for tensorflow_decision_forests rleated packages in anaconda to be able to import it into my code.

Answer (score 1):

`pip3 install tensorflow_decision_forests --upgrade`

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests#installation

However, from

https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/issues/16

the latest pip version is for linux only. Therefore, if you are a mac user, you can download it from

https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/releases/tag/0.2.3

Comment: This is what I have been trying, But it gives me the error I mentioned. Thank you

Comment: @Oreo what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows. But, Do you mean I can use this code in a mac to install tensorflow_decision_forests packages?

Comment: @Oreo I guess the best bet is to create a docker with ubuntu